# deletable 'Tags' in a field

Tags: javascript

I want to realize the same Tags-field like here on StackExchange while editing/adding a post. I want the option to choose different tags from a list, delete and sort them (last one is not included here). I don't need the ajax-autocomplete functionality – the tags should be picked from a list I generate. Also there is no option to create new tags.
an ID and sorting-weight should be saved in a hidden field, so I can pass this values by submitting a form

is there somehow a UI which provides all this? doesn't matter which library

thx in advanced

Comment: Javascript is front end technology, so I don't know why you've put "backend" on your question.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I meant the backend of a CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) is a jQuery plugin which allows your users to select multiple items from a predefined list, using autocompletion as they type to find each item. You can style the list with different themes or create yours.